# Python table how to scrape with bs4

Tags: python

I have been trying to figure out how to scrape a table off a website using BS4 and the HTML, and I've been seeing the same type of code around this forum.

```
from bs4 import NavigableString

url="https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020.html"
res = requests.get(url)
id="all_misc_stats"
html = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
data=pd.read_html(html.find_all(string=lambda x: isinstance(x, NavigableString) and id in x))

pace=pd.read_html(data)[0]
```

I'm trying to get the Miscellaneous stats table, but it keeps telling me it is either out of range or cannot parse. What should I do?

Comment: I don't know what your "NavigableString" lambda is trying to do.  If you just feed the whole `html` into pandas, do you get something usable?  It looks like that site is well-behaved, and all the data in in `<table>s`, which pandas likes.

Comment: No pandas can't read the table directly from HTML for this one. I think it has something to do with Javascript is what somebody told me on here last time.

Comment: The data are all in the HTML; it's not generated dynamically.  You can try `data = pd.read_html( html.find("div#div_divs_standing_E"))` and see how that does;   That isolates the Eastern Conference from the rest of the page.

Comment: It says it cannot parse from 'NoneType' once I typed that out

Answer (score 0):

The table data you are looking for is placed inside an `HTML comment`, so a possible solution would be to parse these elements, and return when it finds the matching `id`.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment #import the Comment object
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020.html"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
for c in comments:
    ele = BeautifulSoup(c.strip(), 'html.parser')
    if tbl := ele.find("table"):
        if (tbl_id := tbl.get("id")) == "misc_stats":
            pace = pd.read_html(str(tbl), header=1)[0]

print(pace.head())
```

Output:

```
    Rk                   Team   Age     W     L  PW  ...  TOV%.1  DRB%  FT/FGA.1             Arena  Attend.  Attend./G
0  1.0       Milwaukee Bucks*  29.2  56.0  17.0  57  ...    12.0  81.6     0.178      Fiserv Forum   549036      17711
1  2.0  Los Angeles Clippers*  27.4  49.0  23.0  50  ...    12.2  77.6     0.206    STAPLES Center   610176      19068
2  3.0    Los Angeles Lakers*  29.5  52.0  19.0  48  ...    14.1  78.8     0.205    STAPLES Center   588907      18997
3  4.0       Toronto Raptors*  26.6  53.0  19.0  50  ...    14.6  76.7     0.202  Scotiabank Arena   633456      19796
4  5.0        Boston Celtics*  25.3  48.0  24.0  50  ...    13.5  77.4     0.215         TD Garden   610864      19090
```

Comment: This is beautiful. I'm trying to figure out how this works so bear with me -- I am new to this. So this looks through the HTML using the beautiful soup HTML parser, then it looks if there's any tables then it searches for the right table id in those loops .... what is the :=

Comment: @bmatt23 this looks through the HTML and extracts all the comments (everything between `<!-- -->`. Then I parse again each of the comments and if the commented content is a `table` element and has a matching id, then read the html into a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: As for the walrus operator `:=`, it's a shorter version for variable assignment. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)

Comment: @bmatt23, be sure to accept the solution if it worked out for you.